# Scoping issue with prototypes and async.forEach

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, coffeescript

I have a scope issue that I don't understand.

I have this object with some methods:

```
FileInfo = (file) ->
   @name = path.basename(file.path);

FileInfo::uploadImage = (filename, callback) ->

FileInfo::handleImage = (version, callback) ->
   # Here I would like to call uploadImage
```

I am calling handleImage from an async.forEach loop as:

```
async.forEach options, fileInfo.handleImage,  (err) -
```

I would like to call uploadImage from within handleImage but I get TypeError: Object # has no method 'uploadImage'

I have tried, inside of handleImage, the following:

```
this.uploadImage
```

as well as:

```
that = this
that.uploadImage
```

Neither work.

If I call fileInfo.handleImage outside of the forEach loop it works fine with either this or that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `fileInfo.handleImage` to `fileInfo.handleImage.bind(fileInfo)` (assuming `fileInfo` is an *instance* of `FileInfo`).

It is losing the `this` binding (that is, the *value* of `this` when that function is executing, not to be confused with the [*execution context*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.3), see comments) that you expect, because you don't immediately invoke it, just pass a reference to it.

Comment: Please, a function's `this` keyword isn't "context". A function's `this` binding is set as a component of establishing an [*execution context*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.3) and is set entirely by the call or use of [`bind`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.5).

Comment: @RobG You don't think referring to it as a *context* is easier for people with less JavaScript experience (which I assumed of the OP)?

Comment: No, because they think of it as being related to *where* the function was called from (i.e. the actual context) rather than *how* it was called. Also, ECMA-262 only uses the word "context" in relation to "execution context", not `this`.

Comment: I think it's reasonable to refer to it as context, as in the context in which it's being executed (not called). I'm not referring to the calling context, just the executing function's context. I'll try and find a better term that doesn't clash with terms defined in ECMA.

Comment: I think that's my point. A function's `this` is a component of its execution context, it doesn't define it. It can be referenced as `this` or "this keyword" for searching.

Comment: @RobG I've updated my answer with your feedback, let me know if you think it's still ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use bind as suggested above or the fat arrow (=>)

However for the fat arrow to work you need to use idiomatic Coffeescript
classes. Building a class the normal Javascript way by assigning prototype
slots wont work.

```
class FileInfo
    constructor: (file) -> 
        @name = path.basename(file.path);

    uploadImage: (filename, callback) ->

                                     ---- fat arrow here
                                     V
    handleImage: (version, callback) =>
    # Here I would like to call uploadImage
```

Using it that way will force the CoffeeScript compiler to generate the binding in Javascript for you.